# iphone css display table wont allow text copy

Tags: ios, css, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I am developing a mobile web app with JQuery Mobile. I have some divs that are laid out as a table using display table, row, cell.

```
    <div class="table detail">
        <div>
            <div class="detailHeadings">Expiration:</div>
            <div class="detailValues">#{viewBean.expiration}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="detailHeadings">ID:</div>
            <div>#{viewBean.Id}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="detailHeadings">Email:</div>
            <div class="detailValues">#{viewBean.email}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="detailHeadings">ZIP Code:</div>
            <div class="detailValues">#{viewBean.zipCode}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With the following css:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    color: #333333;
    table-layout: fixed;

}

.table > div {
    display: table-row;
}

.detail .detailValues {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.detailHeadings {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

This works fine, however I want to be able to copy just the Id. When I do a long press on windows phone or android I can select the id just fine. However, on iOS it only allows me to select the entire table. This is a problem anytime I use `display:table`. Is there a way to let iOS know what I want to be able to copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below to your CSS:

```
.table div .detailHeadings, .table div:not(:nth-child(2)) .detailHeadings + div {
    -khtml-user-select: none;     
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;     
    user-select: none;     
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;     
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I tried both of those solutions with no luck. Setting user-select does make the entire table non selectable but I cant do a long press on just the ID at that point.

Comment: Try just adding: `.table div .detailHeadings, .table div:not(:nth-child(2)) .detailHeadings + div {
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}` to your CSS

Comment: That works perfectly in a desktop browser but not on iOS safari.

Comment: @ferics2 - great, glad it solved everything for you!